# Adding a calculated column to a data matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a data matrix with several columns, with Revenue, Cost_Unit and Quantity being some of them. I want to append a "Profit" column to my matrix, calculated as Revenue - Cost_Unit*Quantity. What's the most efficient way to do this? There might be a million rows in my matrix so I want it to be as fast as possible.

This is the error I'm getting. Could anyone help me out please?

```
 final_set$Profit = final_set$Revenue - (final_set$Cost_Unit*final_set$Quantity)
```

Error in `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  RHS of assignment to new column 'Profit' is zero length but not empty list(). For new columns the   RHS must either be empty list() to create an empty list column, or, have length > 0; e.g. NA_integer_, 0L, etc.

Comment: `QUANTITY` and `Quantity` are not the same thing; is this just a typo in the column name?

Comment: yeah that was a typo, I fixed that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have the following data:

```
set.seed(1)

Cost_Unit <- rnorm(10, 100, 10)
Quantity <- rnorm(10, 1000, 100)
Revenue <- Cost_Unit*runif(10,1.02,1.1)*Quantity
final_set <- data.frame(Cost_Unit, Quantity, Revenue)

final_set$Profit <- with(final_set, Revenue - Cost_Unit * Quantity)
```

This will give you:

```
#   Cost_Unit  Quantity   Revenue   Profit
#1   93.73546 1151.1781 117151.15 9244.941
#2  101.83643 1038.9843 113399.64 7593.181
#3   91.64371  937.8759  93052.92 7102.482
#4  115.95281  778.5300  96072.12 5799.383
#5  103.29508 1112.4931 122083.18 7168.122
#6   91.79532  995.5066  98981.19 7598.346
#7  104.87429  998.3810 106994.02 2289.520
#8  107.38325 1094.3836 124355.50 6837.037
#9  105.75781 1082.1221 123436.37 8993.504
#10  96.94612 1059.3901 110449.52 7745.766
```

Comment: Also `final_set <- transform(final_set, Revenue - Cost_Unit * Quantity)` (though that's generally more helpful when you need to change multiple columns).